# Access to root context in Handlebar.js template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is there any built-in method for accessing the root context in a Handlebars.js template?
Most of the helpers are adding a nested context and you have to write ../ before the variable in that context to access it but that is not very practical if you have lots of eachs, ifs, etc.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use @root.  This is in handlebars-v2.0.0.js

```
{{@root.somthing.nested_somthing}}
```

Comment: You can also use @root in `if` and `each` blocks, e.g. `{{#each @root.somthing.nested_somthing}}`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the version, where it was introduced. We were failing until we realized we were working with handlebars-v.1.3.0.js

Answer (score 8):

there is no possibility to access root context of template once you change the context
with looping (e.g. each) [more info](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/392)

However there is a possibility to access previous context with `'../'`

```
# app/assets/javascript/contents.coffee
body = HandlebarsTemplates['my_hbs_template']({
  view:{
    registryName: 'foo',
    data: {items: {x: 'x'}}
    }
  })
```

template:

```
<!-- app/assets/javascript/templates/my_content.hbs -->
<table class="table">
  <tbody>

  {{#each view.data.items}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{@key}}</td>
      <td>
        Hello from {{../view.registryName}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

check http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths  for more info

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have created one see http://www.my2ndgeneration.com/TemplateLanguageDoc.aspx#xroot

Basically, add this helper and bingo {{xRoot}} will take you to the top ...

I always pass my JSON data into handlebars like this:

```
{ data: self.data }
```

thus the code below always returns "data" when it sees the xRoot tag and takes me to the top

```
Handlebars.JavaScriptCompiler.prototype.nameLookup = function (parent, name, type) {

    if (name.indexOf("xRoot") === 0) {
        return "data";
    }

    if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(name)) {
        return parent + "[" + name + "]";
    } else if (Handlebars.JavaScriptCompiler.isValidJavaScriptVariableName(name)) {
        return parent + "." + name;
    }
    else {
        return parent + "['" + name + "']";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as yet!

It has been suggested a few times and there is an open ticket: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/392

Their argument is that it isn't required but if it is a cheap fix with no discernible performance overhead I don't see why it can't be included.